# Vulkan: What did vkQueuePresentKHR do?

Tags: vulkan

```
void drawFrame() {

    vkWaitForFences(device, 1, &inFlightFences[currentFrame], VK_TRUE, std::numeric_limits<uint64_t>::max());

    ...

    VkSemaphore signalSemaphores[] = {renderFinishedSemaphores[currentFrame]};
    submitInfo.signalSemaphoreCount = 1;
    submitInfo.pSignalSemaphores = signalSemaphores;

    vkQueueSubmit(graphicsQueue, 1, &submitInfo, inFlightFences[currentFrame])

    ...

    VkSwapchainKHR swapChains[] = {swapChain};

    VkPresentInfoKHR presentInfo = {};
    presentInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PRESENT_INFO_KHR;
    presentInfo.waitSemaphoreCount = 1;
    presentInfo.pWaitSemaphores = signalSemaphores;
    presentInfo.swapchainCount = 1;
    presentInfo.pSwapchains = swapChains;
    presentInfo.pImageIndices = &imageIndex;

    vkQueuePresentKHR(presentQueue, &presentInfo); // <- vkQueuePresentKHR
    ...

    currentFrame = (currentFrame + 1) % MAX_FRAMES_IN_FLIGHT;
}
```

VkQueuePresentKHR is called for presont after the first frame vkQueueSubmit is submitted, In the second frame, call vkWaitForFences to wait for the vkQueueSubmit of the previous frame to end and then call vkQueueSubmit again to commit, But at this point the first frame of vkQueuePresentKHR may be in the rendering, it occupies the Framebuffer of the first frame. So will the vkQueueSubmit of the second frame conflict with the vkQueuePresentKHR of the first frame?

**I think there may be two situations:**

1：The first frame and the second frame do not occupy the same Framebuffer，When the first frame vkQueueSubmit ends, the data has been copied to a new memory. vkQueuePresentKHR presents the data in the new memory, so rendering the second frame to the Framebuffer does not affect the content of the first frame.

2：The first frame and the second frame occupy the same Framebuffer，When the vkQueuePresentKHR of the first frame and the vkQueueSubmit of the second frame use the Framebuffer at the same time, a tearing of the picture occurs (I guess).

I think the second possibility will be higher.

I want to render the result into my own memory instead of presont it to the screen. I want to figure out what vkQueuePresentKHR does.

Here is an example of rendering to your own memory：https://github.com/SaschaWillems/Vulkan/blob/master/examples/renderheadless/renderheadless.cpp

In this example, the rendered Framebuffer data is transferred to new memory.

In the program I designed, there is a secondary thread responsible for waiting for the Fence to be completed. This memory is used once the transfer is complete. Similar to the example below:

Primary thread:

```
void drawFrame() {

    vkWaitForFences(device, 1, &inFlightFences[currentFrame], VK_TRUE, std::numeric_limits<uint64_t>::max());

    ...

    VkSemaphore signalSemaphores[] = {renderFinishedSemaphores[currentFrame]};
    submitInfo.signalSemaphoreCount = 1;
    submitInfo.pSignalSemaphores = signalSemaphores;

    // VkQueueSubmit(graphicsQueue, 1, &submitInfo, inFlightFences[currentFrame]) cannot be executed before the execution of 
    // vkQueueSubmit(graphicsQueue, 1, &transferSubmitInfo, transferCompleteFences[currentFrame]) in the previous frame. Otherwise,
    // they will occupy the same FrameBuffer. I think it is not possible.
    transferCompleteMutexs[currentFrame].lock();                                                // <- lock transferCompleteMutexs

    vkQueueSubmit(graphicsQueue, 1, &submitInfo, inFlightFences[currentFrame])

    ...

    VkSubmitInfo transferSubmitInfo = {};
    transferSubmitInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_SUBMIT_INFO;
    transferSubmitInfo.commandBufferCount = 1;
    transferSubmitInfo.pCommandBuffers = &commandBuffer;
    transferSubmitInfo.waitSemaphoreCount = 1;
    transferSubmitInfo.pWaitSemaphores = signalSemaphores;
    vkQueueSubmit(graphicsQueue, 1, &transferSubmitInfo, transferCompleteFences[currentFrame]) // Signal <- transferCompleteFences
    ...
}
```

Secondary thread:

```
while(true) {
    // Waiting for transfer to complete
    vkWaitForFences(logicalDevice_->vkLogicalDevice(),
                    1,
                    &transferCompleteFences[currentFrame],                         // Wait <- transferCompleteFences
                    VK_TRUE,
                    std::numeric_limits<uint64_t>::max());

    // using transfer completed data 
    ...

    // Secondary thread knows that the current frame is transmitted. The next Primary thread can be submitted.
    transferCompleteMutexs[currentFrame].unlock();                              　　// <- unlock transferCompleteMutexs
}
```

The above code uses **transferCompleteMutexs** to protect FrameBuffer, I think this is necessary. But obviously vkQueuePresentKHR doesn't do this. Do I have a better way to emulate vkQueuePresentKHR to render the data into my own memory, or is it correct that I am doing now?

Comment: "*So will the vkQueueSubmit of the second frame conflict with the vkQueuePresentKHR of the first frame?*" That depends entirely on what you're submitting. Since you don't say, there's no way this question can be answered.

Answer (score 0):

`vkQueueSubmit` of the second frame cannot "conflict" with `vkQueuePresent` of the first frame.

In the second frame you would also do a `vkAcquireNextImage`, which gives a semaphore. Provided the semaphore is signaled, the Image is not used by the Presentation Engine anymore (irregardless if it is the same Image as for the previous frame or not).

What `vkQueueSubmit` can conflict with though is the previous `vkQueueSubmit` and various resources that uses.

What `vkQueuePresent` does is submit your semaphore wait for execution before it returns. It will not access the image before the semaphore is signaled. It will present the picture in the Image outside\asynchronously from the Vulkan queue. Anything else is unspecified. The image can be copied, copied just-in-time, or used directly, or anything else that fits the above API contract.

Comment: Thank you, I understand, then can vulkan produce OpenGL vertical synchronization Screen tearing?

Comment: [VkPresentModeKHR](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.1-khr-extensions/html/vkspec.html#VkPresentModeKHR)